# Is it ok to return in main?

Tags: rust

Since mains return type is an empty tuple `()`, is it considered a work-around to use `return;` in `fn main()` ? I'd like to end my program but don't want to `panic!` , I just want to calmly end. Is there a standard way to end main early? Or is this ok to do? I come from a C++ background where if you need to return early from a function which does not return any value, you *probably* shouldn't be using a `void` to begin with, so I'm wondering if this is the same case with no return type for `main()`?

```
fn main() {
    // ...

    // if no cline args display usage and end
    if matches.free.is_empty() {
        print_usage(&program, options);
        return;

    // program continues
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's perfectly fine at the language level to return early like this. In this case, you might also like the [`std::process::exit`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html) function, which also allows setting the return code of the process.

Comment: Are destructors going to be called when you use `std::process::exit`?

Comment: @WiSaGaN: “Note that because this function never returns, and that it terminates the process, no destructors on the current stack or any other thread's stack will be run. If a clean shutdown is needed it is recommended to only call this function at a known point where there are no more destructors left to run.”

Comment: Any reason why we can't simply return an error-code from main like usual?  `std::process::exit` seems rather cumbersome to use.

Comment: The note on destructors shouldn't matter too much as long as you're using `std::process::exit` in the main method instead of arbitrarily in the app due to guarantees rust makes about ownership. I foresee it becoming a bit trickier when multithreading comes into play though.